# HTML Number Input Step Not Validating

Tags: html, validation, input, numbers

I have two different number-type input fields, both with a declared min, max, and step. On one, the step works just fine with the arrows/spinner, and throws an error when someone manually enters a number that isn't divisible by the step value. The second number input field, set up exactly the same way, the step works fine with the arrows/spinner, but will allow someone to manually enter whatever value they want, and even submit the form with the "incorrect" number. (Example: step="2", and they entered and were able to submit a 5.)

the two boxes are on different pages, and the one that's giving me fits looks like this

```
<input style="width:75px;" type="number" id="updates_23705616199" max="120" name="updates[]" class="txtbox" value="2" min="2" data-id="23705616199" step="2">
```

I even extracted just this line to an html file by itself, and it still doesn't work then. The data-id field is a required bit for the page that it's in.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your IDs are unique? I created a JSFiddle showing your example working. I also gave them unique names.

https://jsfiddle.net/pa9rodfL/

```
<input type="number" id="idName" class="className" name="nameName" min="11" max="15" step="2" >

<input type="number" id="idName2" class="className" name="nameName2" min="5" max="10" step="3" >
```

Comment: The boxes themselves are on different pages; That may have been something that I should have mentioned. Although, for what it's worth, their IDs are different.

Comment: Further update: I grabbed the specific line, which happens to have a few data fields required by the page that it's in, and when just that line is extracted into an html page by itself, it doesn't work either.     <input style="width:75px;" type="number" id="updates_23705616199" max="120" name="updates[]" class="txtbox" value="2" min="2" data-id="23705616199" step="2">

Comment: Can you update your original question with the actual code?

Comment: Updated, as requested. For some reason the edit button was hiding from me the first several times that I viewed my question, else I would have updated it then.

Comment: I pasted the code you provided into a JSFiddle, and it ran without any issues, it does not let a form post. Can you provide the rest of your code? The error is not in the line you showed me.

Comment: Unfortunately that would involve releasing proprietary code.

Comment: I understand, I hope you found the error. As I said, the error must be somewhere else. If you need anymore help, let me (or the community) know.